# jsf transient view creates @ViewScope error

Tags: jsf, stateless

I am running into a problem where my stateless views generate the following error

> @ViewScoped beans are not supported on stateless views

I set up a little test and found the below very simplified version of my page with no backing bean will generate the error.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <f:view transient="true">
        <h:body>
            test
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

If I remove the,

```
<h:body>
```

Tags the error will not be generated. I'm guessing that this has something to do with the servlet JSF is automatically generating in the background, but after a ton of Googling, I can't seem to find a solution.

How can I use a stateless view with standard JSF?

Comment: The code does not seem to be having the h:html, h:head tags.. thus not making it a html page..

Comment: An `h:body` in a `ui:composition` is also not very common...